# WIF: Passing SecurityToken between R-STS and RP

Tags: .net, wif

I have developed a R-STS with Framework .NET 4.5 using WSFederationAuthenticationModule.
This R-STS redirect the request to the correct identity provider (custom STS, ADFS, ecc).
In the event WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated in the R-STS, I can see the correct token retrieved and validated.
In the realm parameter there is the Url of the RP Web Site.
How can I pass this token to the RP (Asp .NET Web Site) and authenticating the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it works, adding a page in the R-STS and doing the sign-in, in the Page_PreRender event.